# Boost.python overloaded constructor for numpy array and python list

Tags: python, boost-python

Given a C++ class exposed with Boost.Python, how do I expose two constructors:

- one that takes a numpy array, and
- another that takes a python list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a 100% on what you mean, but I'm assuming that you want to have a constructor taking a Python list and another one taking a numpy array.  There are a couple of ways to go about this.  The easiest way is by using the make_constructor function and overloading it:

```
using boost;
using boost::python;

shared_ptr<MyClass> CreateWithList(list lst)
{
    // construct with a list here
}

shared_ptr<MyClass> CreateWithPyArrayObject(PyArrayObject* obj)
{
    // construct with numpy array here
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule)
{
    class_<MyClass, boost::noncopyable, boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> >
        ("MyClass", no_init)
        .def("__init__", make_constructor(&CreateWithList))
        .def("__init__", make_constructor(&CreateWithPyArrayObject))
}
```

You can be even more clever and use an arbitrary type/number of arguments in your constructor.  This requires a bit of voodoo to accomplish.  See http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/HowTo#A.22Raw.22_constructor for a way to expose a raw function definition as a constructor.

Comment: Thanks. This looks great!  Where is PyArrayObject defined? (I am using MacPorts and have installed py27-numpy, but that doesn't seem to expose any headers with PyArrayObject. I looked for dev variants, but couldn't find any.)

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this without the boost::shared_ptr?  Or else, is there a way to wrap my other static member functions that return MyClass so that they return shared_ptr?

Comment: I got this working with shared_ptr!  However, I still can't find any header with PyArrayObject. I will just ask another question.  Thanks again for your detailed help.

Comment: @NeilG: The numpy api is all defined in `<numpy/arrayobject.h>`.