# C++ lambda; class factory adaptor

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, factory-pattern

Given a class factory

```
struct C {
    C Factory(A a, B b, ...) { ... }
};
```

I want to transform it into a function that returns a shared pointer in an automated way.  Something like:

```
template<T (*f)(Args...), typename T, typename... Args>
boost::shared_ptr<T> blah(Args... args) {
  return boost::shared_ptr<T>(new T(f(args...)));
}
```

that I can use like:

```
shared_ptr<C> c = blah<C::Factory>(a, b, ...);
```

I am using gcc4.4, but I can upgrade to 4.5 for lambdas if necessary.  I'm doing this because after I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713795/boost-python-overloaded-constructor-for-numpy-array-and-python-list), I now need to convert my class factories to return shared_ptr, but I don't want to change my class definitions — just build an adaptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure I understand the quesiton but a few points:

1) The factories should return pointers to **dynamically allocated** objects if you want to use them with boost::smart_ptr. Using smart pointers (which will attempt to delete objects when they go out of scope and no other smart_ptr has ownership of the object) with statically allocated variables makes no sense.

2) When you do return a pointer (your struct code would look something like this)

```
struct C {
    C() { ... };
    static C* Factory(A a, B b) { 
        ...;
        return new C;
    }
};
```

then you can just do

```
boost::shared_ptr<C> p_C(C::Factory(a,b));
```

so I am not really sure if this (possibly very complicated) template function would be so useful.
(To me this use of the factory pattern also seems strange - AFAIK you usually want to abstract the exact type of object being created, but that is another point).

Edit: (Reply to comment, since you can't format comments...)

I am pretty sure that using shared_ptr's which point to statically allocated variables will lead to double delete errors (at least if the objects destructors are deleting anything).. it is surely a dangerous path

Can't you just do (copy from linked question)

```
shared_ptr<MyClass> CreateWithList(list lst) 
{
   return shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(lst)); // construct with a list here
}

shared_ptr<MyClass> CreateWithPyArrayObject(PyArrayObject* obj)
{
    return shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(obj)); // construct with numpy array here
}
```

? 
I mean I'm sure the real case is more complicated then that, but right now it seems easier than the template stuff.

Btw: If you are just after C-type speeds in python, give [Cython](http://cython.org) a try, it's really cool (even if it's not applicable now, it might be in the future...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The reason that my factories are returning by value is that that is what makes sense for the types I'm using.  It allows me to write code like `A a = A::FactoryX(...) + A::FactoryY(...)`.  I need the shared_ptr adaptor solely for dealing with boost.python, which wants functions that return shared_ptr.

Comment: `A a = A::FactoryX(...) + A::FactoryY(...)` do you need the factory pattern here? why not `A a = A(..) + A(...)`, you can overload the constructors with different parameterizations and I don't really see how your code would help with polymorphism either...

Comment: I essentially have named constructors because otherwise it's too confusing.  These classes represent probability distributions.  So, for example:


    GaussianMD(): myMean(0.0), myDeviation(0.0) {}
    GaussianMD(double m, double d): myMean(m), myDeviation(d) {}
    static GaussianMD degenerate(double m) { return GaussianMD(m, 0.0); }

Comment: I'm going to mark you as correct, as I'm going to give up on this now.  Thanks for your help.